# How to change triple or more click response?

Tags: macos, trackpad

Let be clear. I upgraded from 10.6.8 to 10.11 (Snow Leopard to El Capitan) a couple of months ago.

I got used to it and even customized all the basic Trackpad and Accessibility settings but I still can't get used to how the triple click works.

In my previous macOS (like in other operating systems) when you quadruple click it's equal to a triple + single click, with the result of selecting whole paragraph and undo this action.

So by clicking *x* times it just cycles this 3 + 1.

But on El Capitan, after triple click I need to wait something that feels as long as 1-2 seconds before allowing single-click to undo whole paragraph selection.

This way if I quadruple click or triple click and failing to wait those 1-2 seconds I could endlessly be stuck in tapping/clicking with no effect and the best option is to press <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Is it possible to set this 3 + 1 click cycle back?

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered how to solve this a while ago, by chance.

I was exploring `System Preferences > Accessibility` and after finishing setting what I needed under the `Keyboard` section I took a look at the `Mouse & Trackpad` one.

The solution was to just increase the `Double-click speed`.

If I recall it right that option wasn't under Accesibility back on Snow Leopard and probably I touched it just once a lifetime ago  (if I had even touched it) and forgot it ever since.

*The sort of things that happens when you don't create documentations*